# (svelte) how can I access previus component props from component

Tags: javascript, components, svelte

how can I access a prop from a same-named component in the same container?

```html
<Container>
 <Line x={10} y={12}>
 <Line x={14} y={8}>
 <Line x={50} y={30}>
</Container>
```

so the second `<Line>` get these props (x, y)

 but also the previous Line props (without that user need to specify it)

so in the second Line Case, it get the 14 and 8, but needs to get also 10, and 12

in the `line.svelte`:

```html
<script>
  export let x;
  export let y;
</script>

<div style="top: {x}px; left: {y}px;" />
```

I need to get the previous x, y because I need to do some calculation and find the angle and connect the 2 lines (and I know the formula).

My idea is something like `document.querySelector("Line")[thisComponetIndex - 1].x;` but isn't possible in Svelte since is compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines are related, I would recommend processing them in a single component, rather than individually. Inter-component communication in Svelte is a bit cumbersome.

So instead of the current markup you do something like:

```html
<Lines items={[
    { x: 10, y: 12 },
    { x: 14, y: 8 },
    { x: 50, y: 30 },
]}/>
```

Then, inside the component you can process the items with `{#each}` and use its index to also access the previous item.

```html
{#each items as item, index}
  {@const previousItem = items[index - 1]}
  ...
{/each}
```

You can still use the `Line` component here, if that is useful to you.

Comment: yeah, this is what I want. can you tell me what `@const` means in svelte?

Comment: It just [defines a local constant](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const) in the scope.

Comment: If your use case becomes more complex, it might become a good idea to use a svelte store. If you just need the previous item, the @H.B. solution should be enough. But if it becomes more complex, a store can help seperate your logic from your layout code. Then, pass that store to the component. `<Lines items={$mystore} /> `